# Pulling/shifting a texture in Open Gl es 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I want to recreate the following effect:

Link of what is to be done.
https://gofile.io/d/KzEUSM

I’ve tried doing so with the following code:
Vertex Code:

```
uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix; // Translated mvp matrix
uniform mat4 u_OriginalMVPMatrix; // Original Untranslated mvp matrix
uniform mat4 u_ScaledMVPMatrix;

attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate;

varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;
varying vec3 v_ShiftingFactor;



void main()
{
vec4 opos = u_OriginalMVPMatrix * a_Position;
vec4 pos = u_MVPMatrix * a_Position;

gl_Position = opos;

v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate;
v_ShiftingFactor = vec3(opos - pos);
}
```

Fragment Code:

```
 precision highp float;

 uniform sampler2D u_Texture;

 varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;
 varying vec3 v_ShiftingFactor;


void main()
{
vec4 originaltexture = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate);
vec4 shiftedTexture = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate +     vec2(v_ShiftingFactor));

 if (originaltexture.a > 0.0 && shiftedTexture.a > 0.0)
 {
     gl_FragColor = shiftedTexture;
 }
 else if (originaltexture.a > 0.0 && shiftedTexture.a == 0.0)
 {
     gl_FragColor = originaltexture; // I’m guessing something has to be done here
 }
 else
 {
     gl_FragColor = originaltexture;
 }


 }
```

I got the following result with this code (using OpenGL es 2.0):

Link to my disaster.

https://gofile.io/d/CIHRto

I know the doubling is being caused by the else if. How do I cause it to pull the texture like it’s being done in the video provided? I’ve tried various stuff, but I just can’t seem to wrap my head around it.
For reference these are the images I’m using:

**Link to rock mask png:**

[image: Link to rock mask png]

**Link to ocean png.**

[image: Link to ocean png.]

Comment: oh boy, 12 minutes to download the video file that shows what you're trying to do. Is there any better way for you to show us the effect?

Comment: The texture is being shifted by a different part at each pixel. But I don't think there's enough info here to calculate that. You need something like a depth map so the shader knows how much to shift each pixel. Then you have to approximate the *opposite* of a depth map shift, which there are algorithms for.

Comment: Is this homework? If it's homework you should have been taught a way to do it.

Comment: It's not homework, just an effect I wanted to recreate. I know that a displacement map can be used, that was my first approach. I wanted to know if there was a simpler way that I was overlooking. Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: The difficulty with doing this kind of displacement in a shader is that the shader has the screen coordinates as input, not the world coordinates. Calculating screen coordinates based on world coordinates is easy; calculating world coordinates based on screen coordinates is called ray-tracing. You can do ray-tracing in a shader but it's not trivial.